# Input control shows incorrect value, even 'though inspect element shows the right value is there

Tags: c#, firefox

I wonder if anyone has experienced this before.

I have a c# .net app which builds an html page including some prepopulated input boxes.

The trouble is that sometimes, some of the input boxes don't have the values I expect. This seems to happen fairly randomly - at least I can't spot the pattern.

I am working in Firefox, and when I press "Inspect Element" for one of the input boxes, the inspector clearly shows the correct expected value in the value= in the HTML, even though the incorrect value is shown on the page.

I have no idea how to go about solving this problem.

Any ideas? I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: can you show what the correct / incorrect value is that's being displayed..??

Comment: Looks like a problem with either the browser or the encodimg of the page... It could probably help if you post more (especially more specific) details.

Comment: I am currently exploring the possibility that it is actually a prior input control on the page which is causing the problem. I am sending something like ' value="£9.99" ' to another field (instead of, for example ' value="&pound;9.99" '. Could that be causing the encoding of the page to fail in the way that @Tobias is enquiring?

Comment: The above seemed to improve things slightly, but has not completely resolved the problem. To see it in action, go to http://coffeebreakfinance.com/Plan.aspx scroll down to the outgoings section, and append a 1 to the end of "forever" in the last column of the second row, then immediately press F5. When the screen refreshes, the "1" has moved to the row above. This happens in Firefox, but not Chrome, and in the Outgoings table, but not the Income table. If you press Ctrl-F5 instead of F5 the problem does not occur. I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: I think I have now solved this second issue using the solution posted for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402891/firefox-3-5-2-refreshf5-causes-highlighted-form-value-to-get-copied-to-next-fi